# Saving terminal output to file line-by-line (writing and closing file after every print)

Tags: linux, files, logs, output, read-write

I have a Python script running on a Linux machine which is printing output out to the terminal. Currently, I'm logging this output to a file using the `script` command. However, the problem with this approach is that I am not able to read the data added to the file while the script is running; I want to periodically `scp` this file onto my local machine to read.

Is there any way I can redirect the output of my script such that file is being appended to and closed after every line is printed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching, I found the solution to my problem:

```
stdbuf -oL python script.py >> log.txt
```

This does exactly what I wanted.